# Bug en la versión móvil de mi landing page

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

Estoy con el siguiente problema.

Realicé una **landing page** personal (*responsive* con Bootstrap). El problema es el siguiente:

> La web comienza con una sección de bienvenida con un background fijo (fixed). Cuando se ve desde el ordenador, la página funciona a la perfección (incluso haciendo uso de la herramienta *responsive* de google chrome). El problema es en el móvil y me di cuenta que entra en conflicto con la barra de navegación de chrome para movil.

Les dejo la página para que puedan ver mejor el bug:

https://faggv.bitbucket.io/

Así se ve cuando carga la imagen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfyjN.jpg

Se ve una porción vacía que coincide con el tamaño de la barra de navegación de chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwOSO.jpg

Comment: He probado la web que expones en el ejemplo (tanto en sobremesa como en dispositivo móvil)  y no veo problema alguno. ¿Podrías subir una imagen del conflicto que nos mencionas para que podamos saber de lo que hablas?

Comment: Creo que ya veo a lo que te refieres. Si quieres que `.caption-container` mida lo mismo de altura que `.principal` para que no te ocurra ese descuadre, tienes dos opciones. 1: Meter `.caption-container` dentro de `.principal`, para que así el `height: 100%` que le tienes puesto haga que ambos tengan la misma altura. 2: Modificar el 'height: 100%' de `.caption-container` para ponerle le mismo que tiene `.principal` (100vh).

Comment: Intenté lo que proponés pero no solucionó el problema. Mi intención no es que midan lo mismo. Mi problema es ese espacio vacío que aparece en mi móvil pero no sucede lo mismo en el PC (en ninguna resolución). Estoy seguro que lo que entra en conflicto es la barra de navegación de chrome mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo creo que tu problema si que es que no midan lo mismo. Al tener `caption-container` con un `height: 100%` le estás diciendo que mida 100% de la altura de su padre, pero a su altura se le está restando la altura de la barra de herramientas de Google Chrome, como bien has apreciado. Por otro lado, tienes tu elemento `.principal`, cuya altura es la totalidad de la altura de la pantalla del dispositivo donde se visualice (100vh). Esta altura no contempla que exista la barra de herramientas de Google Chrome, por lo que no se le resta.

> Altura de `.principal` = altura de pantalla del dispositivo.
>   Altura de `.caption-container` = altura de pantalla del dispositivo - barra de
>   herramientas
>   Altura de `.principal` > altura de `.caption-container`.
>
> **Resultado:** Hueco sin cubrir por `.caption-container`

Por eso, lo que he hecho ha sido meter `.caption-container` dentro de `.principal` y dado que `.principal` tiene un `position: relative` y `.caption-container` un `position: absolute` este último va a tomar como referencia la posición de su padre, pudiendo darle un `top: 0px` para que se posiciones justo al inicio. Haciendo esto las reglas `top: 50%;` y `transform: translateY(-50%);` no te son necesarias.

```css
.principal {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
}

.princ-wrap {
    clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.princ-inner {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    will-change: transform;
    background-image: url('https://faggv.bitbucket.io//img/principal.jpg');
}

.caption-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center!important;
}

.caption h1 {
    color: rgb(243, 245, 166);
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    text-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.8rem black;
}

.caption h3 {
    color: rgb(243, 245, 166);
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.5rem black;
}

.caption .btn-lg {
    color: rgb(243, 245, 166);
    border-color: rgb(243, 245, 166);
    border-width: medium;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.3rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 1rem black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="principal" id="home">
  <div class="princ-wrap">
    <div class="princ-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="caption-container">
    <div class="caption text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Bienvenido a mi Sitio</h1>
      <h3>FAGGV Desarrollador Web</h3>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="#sobreMi">Empecemos</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sobreMi">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8  text-center">
          <p class="lead">
            "... Mi nombre es Federico García García Verdier. Soy Ingeniero
            Químico y Desarrollador Web. Me encuentro comenzando en el
            proceso de reorientar mi profesión hacia la programación.
          </p>
          <p class="lead">
            Soy una persona proactiva y resolutiva. Estoy buscando la
            oportunidad de integrarme a un equipo de trabajo que me permita
            pontenciar aún mas mis habilidades ..."
          </p>
          <a href="CV/CV Fede.pdf" download="FGGV CV.pdf" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Descarga mi CV
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <img src="img/yo.jpeg" alt="foto personal">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid  text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="my-4 title-line">
        <h4 class="display-4">Conocimientos Tecnológicos</h4>
        <hr class="my-4 title-line">
      </div>

      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="HTML5">
        <i class="fab fa-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="CSS3">
        <i class="fab fa-css3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="JavaScript">
        <i class="fab fa-js-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="React.js">
        <i class="fab fa-react" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Bootstrap">
        <i class="fab fa-bootstrap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="mySQL">
        <img class="fab fa-mysql" src="img/mysqlicon.png" alt="" aria-hidden="true">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Node.js">
        <i class="fab fa-node-js" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <hr class="linea-abajo mb-5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Miguel era como vos decis. Igualmente lo que hice fue agregarle filter en vez de el div superpuesto. Gracias!